# how to set maximum login user cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-cookies

HOW TO CHECK HOW MANY USERS ARE LOGIN in cakephp

I've tried saving session in my database (i follow this tutorial : [CakePHP 2.0 – Storing Sessions in the database and retrieving online users](https://thomasv.nl/2013/01/cakephp-2-0-storing-sessions-in-the-database-and-retrieving-online-users/) ), now my users cannot login at all

can everybody please help me, or give me reference to solve this problem. or anyone have another way?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your user details table which is used to store email and password add an additional column like `login_count'` with its default value to `0`.

And on each successful login increment its value by `1` and on each logout decrements its value by `1`. By using this column you can put maximum user login at a time limit in your application.

Comment: What happens if a user simply shut down his computer and not click on "logout" ... how is the system supposed to know that he's not logged in anymore?

Comment: @Twinfriends : thanks for your help, i also need to handle it

Comment: No problem, I think the question is really interesting and I would love to see a good solution. Think this one isn't bad, but it won't work in all cases... Thats why I ask, I would like to learn how to do handle that.